# How can I order items due to the values of internal element?

Tags: jquery, sorting

I have this code:

```
<div id="main-container">
    <div class="comunicato-item">
        <div class="item item-1">Marco</div>
        <div class="item item-2">3</div>
        <div class="item item-2">2012</div>
    </div>

    <div class="comunicato-item">
        <div class="item item-1">Andrea</div>
        <div class="item item-2">2</div>
        <div class="item item-2">2013</div>
    </div>  

    <div class="comunicato-item">
        <div class="item item-1">Paul</div>
        <div class="item item-2">9</div>
        <div class="item item-2">2003</div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

and I'd like to order the `comunicato-item` items due to the (for example) `.item.item-2` element value. So the result should be, after the sorting:

```
<div id="main-container">
    <div class="comunicato-item row">
        <div class="item item-1">Andrea</div>
        <div class="item item-2">2</div>
        <div class="item item-2">2013</div>
    </div>  

    <div class="comunicato-item row">
        <div class="item item-1">Marco</div>
        <div class="item item-2">3</div>
        <div class="item item-2">2012</div>
    </div>

    <div class="comunicato-item row">
        <div class="item item-1">Paul</div>
        <div class="item item-2">9</div>
        <div class="item item-2">2003</div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Is it possible with jquery? Tried with somethings like this:

```
var a = [];
$(".comunicato-item .item.item-2").each(function(i,e){
    a.push(e);
});
$.each(a.sort(),function(i,e){
    $("#"+e).appendTo('#main-container');
});
```

but it fails! Any idea?

Comment: ascending sorting due to the item-2 value. In the example, 2-3-9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort the collection like this using the [.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function.  Theres no need to loop through and push it into an array since jQuery already stores the elements in an array.  There's also no need to loop through and append the elements

```
var x = $('#main-container > .comunicato-item').sort(function(a,b){
    var f = +$(a).find('.item-2:first').text();
    var s = +$(b).find('.item-2:first').text();
    return f-s; // no need for if/else because these are numbers
});
$('#main-container').html(x);
// or $('#main-container').append(x);
// or x.appendTo('#main-container');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SuCyz/

**EDIT**

if sorting by words you will have to use if/else

```
var x = $('#comunicato-items > .comunicato-item').sort(function(a,b){
    var f = $(a).find('.item-2:first').text();
    var s = $(b).find('.item-2:first').text();
    return f > s ? 1 : f < s ? -1 : 0;   
});
$('#comunicato-items').html(x);
```

where

```
f > s ? 1 : f < s ? -1 : 0;
```

equal to

```
if(f > s){
   return 1;
}else if(f < s){
   return -1;
}else{
   return 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u5Nxw/

Comment: It doesnt works with my "real" example http://jsfiddle.net/SuCyz/1/ . But it is similar...uhm...

Comment: actually your real example has a different id.. so you need to change it so it matches

Comment: Yeah, typo error! Setted the right now, still doesnt works http://jsfiddle.net/SuCyz/6/

Comment: I'm sorting by "Text". So what matter is the first letters :)

Comment: Well, nice one! But if I wish descending? Just `f > s ? -11 : f < s ? 1 : 0;` ?

Comment: @markzzz yup.. just reverse the logic `<` and `>`.. or switch the `-1` and `1`

Answer (score 2):

You were close, but the sort method would need a function to evaluate the array in this instance...

```
var a = [];

$(".comunicato-item").each(function() {
    a.push(this);
});

a.sort(function(x, y) {
    var xval = parseInt($(".item-2:first", x).text(), 10);
    var yval = parseInt($(".item-2:first", y).text(), 10);
    if (xval > yval) return 1;
    else if (xval < yval) return -1;
    else return 0;
});

$.each(a, function() {
    $(this).appendTo('#main-container');
});
```